# How to connect to a Portal for ArcGIS js API

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have some issues connecting to my ArcGis Portal JavaScript API. I don't know what to specify in:

- require(["in here"], 
      function (in here) {

});
And also where to put authentification parameters ?
they make it look quite simple in that Esri documentation: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/portal-amd.html.

And I tried many times without success.
Can anybody help me with that ?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS-JS_API 3.x or 4.x? The documentation link is for the 3rd, but the question-tag is for the 4th one...